# How can I upload (FTP) files to server in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm trying to write a Bash script that uploads a file to a server. How can I achieve this? Is a Bash script the right thing to use for this?

Comment: The solution is not for ftp protocole but for ssh.

Comment: The accepted solution includes both ftp and ssh.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Below are two answers. First is a suggestion to use a more secure/flexible solution like ssh/scp/sftp. Second is an explanation of how to run ftp in batch mode.

### A secure solution:

You really should use SSH/SCP/SFTP for this rather than FTP. SSH/SCP have the benefits of being more secure and working with public/private keys which allows it to run without a username or password.

You can send a single file:

```
scp <file to upload> <username>@<hostname>:<destination path>
```

Or a whole directory:

```
scp -r <directory to upload> <username>@<hostname>:<destination path>
```

For more details on setting up keys and moving files to the server with RSYNC, which is useful if you have a lot of files to move, or if you sometimes get just one new file among a set of random files, take a look at:

http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html

You can also execute a single command after sshing into a server:

From `man ssh`

> ssh [...snipped...] hostname [command] If command is specified, it is
> executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

So, an example command is:

```
ssh username@hostname.example bunzip file_just_sent.bz2
```

If you can use SFTP with keys to gain the benefit of a secured connection, there are two tricks I've used to execute commands.

First, you can pass commands using echo and pipe

```
echo "put files*.xml" | sftp -p -i ~/.ssh/key_name username@hostname.example
```

You can also use a batchfile with the `-b` parameter:

```
sftp -b batchfile.txt ~/.ssh/key_name username@hostname.example
```

### An FTP solution, if you really need it:

If you understand that FTP is insecure and more limited and you really really want to script it...

There's a great article on this at http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.example.com'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

The `-n` to ftp ensures that the command won't try to get the password from the current terminal. The other fancy part is the use of a heredoc: the `<<END_SCRIPT` starts the heredoc and then that exact same `END_SCRIPT` on the beginning of the line by itself ends the heredoc. The `binary` command will set it to binary mode which helps if you are transferring something other than a text file.

Comment: I would like to do this! Can you please expand on how I can do this? I need to do some things with ssh after uploading the file. Can this be done in one session?

Comment: While it was useful advice for the OP, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. It doesn't answer the original question (that is found via Google)

Comment: Some of the other posters have added binary mode (i.e. `bin`) to the FTP commands. Since yours is the accepted answer, I recommend you adding this to your answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer including both ssh and FTP. I don't understand the fuss about FTP. Maybe I'm working for a client who's website is on FTP and I just don't care, I care only about what the client wants to have done with his website.

Comment: Can also type `hash` to show progress of the ftp transmission in a way. Also, you will usually see `<<EOF` as in End Of File.

Comment: If you need to upload to **another port**, use `scp -P 22 <file> <user>@<host>:<path>` (change 22 to the port you need)

Comment: How about if TLS is required for the ftp script solution?

Comment: @AlvaroB I suggest asking that with more detail as a new question.

Comment: what is the `binary` in the script ?

Comment: @SayanDasgupta as the answer says "The binary command will set it to binary mode which helps if you are transferring something other than a text file." If you are transferring images, pdfs, documents, zips, archives you want binary mode. If you know you are only transferring literal text files (e.g. source code, csvs) then skipping the binary might save you a tiny amount of time.

Answer (score 83):

You can use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to do this, e.g.

```
ftp -n $Server <<End-Of-Session
# -n option disables auto-logon

user anonymous "$Password"
binary
cd $Directory
put "$Filename.lsm"
put "$Filename.tar.gz"
bye
End-Of-Session
```

so the [`ftp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) process is fed on standard input with everything up to `End-Of-Session`. It is a useful tip for spawning any process, not just `ftp`! Note that this saves spawning a separate process ([echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo), [cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat), etc.). It is not a major resource saving, but it is worth bearing in mind.

Comment: This is totally confusing. How do I get out of this End-Of-Session thing? Why not input directly to the ftp prompt that comes without that?

Comment: @erikb85 - this for scripts, not (necessarily) for interactive use. The heredoc will automatically register an act upon your 'End-Of-Session' marker (you'd likely use EOF or similar)

Answer (score 38):

The `ftp` command isn't designed for scripts, so controlling it is awkward, and getting its exit status is even more awkward.

[Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is made to be scriptable, and also has the merit that you can easily switch to other protocols later by just modifying the URL. If you put your FTP credentials in your [.netrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html), you can simply do:

```
# Download file
curl --netrc --remote-name ftp://ftp.example.com/file.bin
# Upload file
curl --netrc --upload-file file.bin ftp://ftp.example.com/
```

If you must, you can specify username and password directly on the command line using `--user username:password` instead of `--netrc`.

Comment: This is the simplier solution.

Comment: `curl` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa). (But neither is [lftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp).)

Answer (score 20):

Install ncftpput and ncftpget.  They're usually part of the same package.

Comment: command line is: "ncftpput -u username -p password server.org /path/ filename.blah"

note that the connection won't be encrypted and the password will be sent in plain text.

Comment: @Adam the "connection won't be encrypted" etc is a consequence of using FTP, which was specified in the question. It's going to happen no matter what FTP client you use.

Answer (score 8):

The command in one line:

```
ftp -in -u ftp://username:password@servername/path/to/ localfile
```

Comment: @erikbwork -u is: "     -u URL file [...] - Upload files on the command line to URL where URL is one of the ftp URL types as supported by auto-fetch (with an optional target filename for single file uploads), and file is one or more local files to be uploaded."

Comment: Which version of ftp are you using? It does not work on ubuntu 18

Answer (score 8):

Use this to upload a file to a remote location:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is the file name
#usage:this_script <filename>
HOST='your host'
USER="your user"
PASSWD="pass"
FILE="abc.php"
REMOTEPATH='/html'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $REMOTEPATH
put $FILE 
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: This is a fairly late answer to not be using .netrc, it is however extendable to delete and gets many of us out of the wput/wget/wdel segmentation violation hole.

Comment: Please login with USER and PASS.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For example, how is it different from previous answers?

Answer (score 4):

```
#/bin/bash
# $1 is the file name
# usage: this_script  <filename>
IP_address="xx.xxx.xx.xx"
username="username"
domain=my.ftp.domain
password=password

echo "
 verbose
 open $IP_address
 USER $username $password
 put $1
 bye
" | ftp -n > ftp_$$.log
```

Comment: you mean echo "..." | ftp -n | ftp_$$.log ?

Comment: At the moment this writes to a file 'ftp' and doesn't spawn an ftp process

Comment: @Yossarian: Only the first `>` should be a `|`

Comment: @ennuikiller: You have spaces around equal signs that Bash doesn't like. Also, hardcoding passwords in cleartext is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm sure the password issue is for illustrative purposes

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any need to complicate stuff. This should work:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "
 verbose
 open ftp.mydomain.net
 user myusername mypassword
 ascii
 put textfile1
 put textfile2
 bin
 put binaryfile1
 put binaryfile2
 bye
" | ftp -n > ftp_$$.log
```

Or you can use [mput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) if you have many files...

Answer (score 3):

Working example to put your file on root...see, it's very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.users.qwest.net'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#$1 is the file name
#usage:this_script <filename>
HOST='yourhost'
USER="youruser"
PASSWD="yourpass"
FILE="abc.php"
REMOTEPATH='/html'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE $REMOTEPATH
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it inside a 'for' to copy the last generated files for an everyday backup...

```
j=0
var="`find /backup/path/ -name 'something*' -type f -mtime -1`"
# We have some files in $var with last day change date

for i in $var
  do
  j=$(( $j + 1 ))
  dirname="`dirname $i`"
  filename="`basename $i`"
  /usr/bin/ftp -in >> /tmp/ftp.good 2>> /tmp/ftp.bad << EOF
    open 123.456.789.012
    user user_name passwd
    bin
    lcd $dirname
    put $filename
    quit
  EOF      # End of ftp
done       # End of 'for' iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "open <ftp.hostname>\nuser <username> <password>\nbinary\nmkdir New_Folder\nquit" | ftp -nv
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For example, what is the idea/gist?