# How to make Uploader in CGI shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cgi, uploader

I want to make uploader script in CGI bash (shell script)

with a "browse" and "submit" to upload files from it

note : the uploader **without** ftp and **without** user and password of ftp or cpanel or sftp

or:

I want to make CGI script "bash", so script can upload files into the web.

Comment: You need to provide some more information. For example:-what have you tried so far?

Comment: :/ my Question was clear -_- how we coded uploader 
the uploader was used to upload files on site 
and i want to coded the uploader in CGI shell script how can 

-_-

Comment: See if this one helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894347/how-to-upload-ftp-files-to-server-in-a-bash-script

Comment: not that helps , i want to make it in CGI and without ftp or sftp and whithout user and password ,

Comment: up please need help -_-

Answer (score 2):

I did this using the example in [Uploading Binary Files in Bash CGI Script](http://tuxx-home.at/archives/2006/04/25/T14_29_04/) but there's a small mistake which we fixed later:

```
file=/tmp/$$-$RANDOM

# CGI output must start with at least empty line (or headers)
printf '\r\n'
  cat <<EOF
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
EOF

IFS=$'\r'
read -r delim_line

IFS=''
delim_line="${delim_line}--"$'\r'

read -r line
filename=$(echo $line | sed 's/^.*filename=//' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/.$//')
fileext=${filename##*.}

while read -r line; do
    test "$line" = '' && break
    test "$line" = $'\r' && break
done

# Note: This will result in junk at end of line (see format above)
cat > $file

# Get the line count
LINES=$(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

# Remove the last line
head -$((LINES - 1)) $file >$file.1

# Copy eveything but the last line to a temp file
head -$((LINES - 2)) $file.1 >$file.2

# Copy the new last line but remove trailing \r\n
tail -1 $file.1 > $file.3
tail -c 2 $file.3 > $file.5
CRLF=$(hexdump -ve '/1 "%.2x"' $file.5)
# Check if the last two bytes are \r\n
if [ "$CRLF" = "0d0a" ];then
   BYTES=$(wc -c $file.3 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
   truncate -s $((BYTES-2)) $file.3
fi

rm $file.5
cat $file.2 $file.3 > $file.4
cp $file.4 $file

cat <<EOF
<h1>Upload Successful</h1>
EOF

cat <<EOF
</body>
</html>
EOF

exit 0
```

Comment: parsley72 very cool solution, thank you. i use your code in my website now. your solution is the only one i found in the whole internet that works for uploading binary files.

Comment: Thank you @parsley72. In my situation, the form data is starting with an additional input text field above the file itself. I had to add these lines after `read -r line` line, in order to gather the extra text: `while read -r line; do
    test "$line" = '' && break
    test "$line" = $'\r' && break
done
IFS=$'\r'
read -r text_input_label
read -r line
IFS=''
read -r line`