# How to write a script in NetBeans to upload a jar on a distant server at build time?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, automation

I'd like to automatize the following:

- when I build my Java SE project on Netbeans, the jar and its dependencies should be uploaded to a server and started.

How do I do that? If scripting or config some xml is involved, Where could I find some tutorial on the syntax to be used?

Comment: What build system do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Maven Invoker Plugin for this and set a postBuildHookScript, as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html). From the script, handle the JAR upload.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894347/how-to-upload-ftp-files-to-server-in-a-bash-script) discusses uploading files to remote servers using bash.