# How to mysqldump to external server?

Tags: mysql, server

At the moment I run a mysqldump on my server that locally saves a database backup:

```
mysqldump -u username -p123456 databasename > /home/www/my-website/backups/$(date +\%m-\%d-\%Y-\%H.\%M.\%S)-username-databasename.sql
```

My goal:
Sending the sql file to an *external* server and saving it there in a folder.

How do I need to adapt my script?

Comment: There are many possible answers to this depending on your environment, do you run in the cloud or bare metal, etc

Comment: Well, I have a webspace with a different hosting provider. I would like to transfer the SQL file to that webspace, using simple FTP. Is this possible?

Comment: Its better to do in 2 steps. 1- dump 2 transfer to that hosting.

Comment: How do I achieve step 2? Also via shell script?

Comment: @KentMiller: yup you can make a folder in hosting2 which is accessible. and then from hosting1, just move file to hosting2/folder via `mv` command (maybe you need to mention ip of hosting2)

Answer (score 0):

you can write ftp script for transferring your backup to destination FTP server. Linux default ftp supports batching.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE="/home/www/my-website/backups/$(date +\%m-\%d-\%Y-\%H.\%M.\%S)-username-databasename.sql"
REMOTE_FILE=/path/to/your/remote/file.sql
HOST='ftp.example.com'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'

mysqldump -u username -p123456 databasename > $FILE

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE $REMOTE_FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894479/1118978)

Comment: How do I specify in which folder on the external server the file will end up?