# FTP Batch Upload Script

Tags: command-line, ftp

Two questions pertaining to a FTP Batch upload script I'm working on.

1)  My log-in script is failing even though I know my credentials are valid.  Any suggestions about this code snippet?

> ```
> open ftp.mydomainname.com
> user (ftp.mydomainname.com:(none)):myusername@mydomaninname.com
> password:mypassword
> ```

2)  This is just a general question about FTP scripts.  If I don't specify a "lcd" will the script assume when I say "put" that it's supposed to get the file from the directory the script lives in, or must I specify the directory with a "lcd"?

Comment: Answered the log-in piece of the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/how-to-script-ftp-upload-and-download

But I'm still having trouble the script can't find the file I'm attempting to "put".  It says file not found whether I specify the "lcd" or not.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I accomplished it like so

put "c:\correct\file\path\here\filename.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered the log-in piece of the question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/

I solved the "lcd"  piece of the question like so

> > put "c:\correct\file\path\here\filename.txt"