# How to download XDCC packs (from IRC bots) from the command-line?

Tags: bash, download, bots, irc

Let's say we have an IRC `#ChannelName` at `irc.server.com` where people can freely download files from the bots, by commands such as `/msg BotName xdcc send #123`, and we want to download one such file into our `/download/dir`. *How to do it in a simple, wget/curl-like, command?*

It may be more than one command, or a script, but bear in mind that I want to encapsulate this into a script so I can just type something along the lines of

```
irc-download.sh irc.server.com ChannelName BotName 123 /download/dir
```

Then wait a while, and have the file, *like it was a wget download.*

Good things to have in a solution:

- Is cross-platform (i.e., Windows binary or source code that can compile into it, or script).
- Has some sort of progress indication.
- Can download two files at the same time (i.e., has no problem connecting twice to same server).
- Is secured against a bad bot sending other unrequested files in the same session.
- Is mostly self-contained (i.e., any needed binaries can run by themselves).

Comment: "bonus-points" ? Are you going to offer a bounty for this coding project? More people will be interested to do that. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry if it came across as entitled. These are just nice things to have in a solution. I just have no experience with using IRC clients and there are so many of them someone might just know 2+ that can be scripted.

Comment: (While I didn't downvote), I may vote to close as "too broad". Did you have some code you needed help with? Else you're asking for a software recommendation which is also off topic. An interesting problem, but as phrased now, off-topic on Stack Overflow(IMHO). Maybe http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com can help you? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter If I was asking "how to download an FTP file through the command line", it wouldn't be considered "software recommendation", right? (alas, searched and [it isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/how-to-script-ftp-upload-and-download)) I'm sure IRC is not much more obscure than FTP, and that there's some "curl/wget" de-facto standard too. If you know of one, I can re-phrase the question as "how can I use irc-curl to download a file".

Comment: IMHO, asking for something that might be listed in a man-page (yes, quite possibly as a poorly documented option (when you're lucky) ;-) ), is either asking for a recommendation or something that belongs on SuperUser.com. Else (slightly) improve your specification, add a 100+ point bounty and see if anyone can produce what you need. (again, IHMO). Wishing your best of luck on finding what you need. Going to bed. Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've looked high and low for a solution that is not super cumbersome (like installing Cygwin on Windows, come on, [there are IRC clients coded in ~250 lines of C](http://tools.suckless.org/sic/), you can even telnet this ****).

And while nobody has simply made a program that does this basic task on a protocol older than your grandma's swimsuits, turns out we live in a world where NodeJS is a thing that exists.

### So yeah, this *is* simple.

First, install these NPM packages (globally with `-g` if you want):

```
npm install irc xdcc progress
```

Then, put this code in `irc-download.js`:

```
var irc = require('xdcc').irc, ProgressBar = require('progress'), progress, arg = process.argv;
var user = 'user_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2), bar = 'Downloading... [:bar] :percent, :etas remaining';
var client = new irc.Client(arg[2], user, { channels: [ '#' + arg[3] ], userName: user, realName: user });
var last = 0, handle = received => { progress.tick(received - last); last = received; };

client.on('join', (channel, nick) => nick == user && client.getXdcc(arg[4], 'xdcc send #' + arg[5], arg[6]));
client.on('xdcc-connect', meta => progress = new ProgressBar(bar, {incomplete: ' ', total: meta.length, width: 40}));
client.on('xdcc-data', handle).on('xdcc-end', r => { handle(r); process.exit(); } ).on('error', m => console.error(m));
```

Then you can use basically the same command line I was going for in the question:

```
node irc-download.js irc.server.com ChannelName BotName 123 /download/dir
```

Javascript is like the Christopher Hitchens of programming or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/namboy94/xdcc-dl as well, if you prefer to use Python.