# Trigger an instance startup, receive files from FTP, process, and upload them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, cloud, windows-server-2012

I'm using an Amazon compute instance with Windows Server 2012 R2 to run some executable I own for data processing.

Right now, what I do it to send my data via FTP (I set up an FTP server on the remote Windows machine), and manually start the data processing. When the processing is completed, I download the outputs back from FTP and manually stop the remote Amazon computing instance.

I want to automate this process. Namely, I want to find a way to automatically start the remote machine when I start sending my data, then automatically trigger the processing (this I can handle via scripting), and then send back the data and shut down the machine automatically (this I think I also can handle).

So, to sum up, I need to know how can I automatically start the machine when I send my data to it.

I am using an FTP server on that machine and an EBS drive, but there may be a better way. Also, does anyone have any more suggestions on this setup?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to automate this. Is your control machine (from where you will be controlling the EC2 instance) a linux or windows machine?

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/): It is the easiest and the most straightforward if you are familiar with ansible. Barely 20 lines of code to achieve what you want. And it is free. You will be using [EC2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) to start/stop your instances and one of many modules to transfer files. However, there is a bit of learning.

[AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/): A one line command to start (or stop) your instance. Once the instance is up and running, you can [automate the file transfer part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/how-to-script-ftp-upload-and-download)