# PowerShell: How to access a file on an FTP server as a string?

Tags: powershell, download, ftp, webclient, ftpwebrequest

I need to download a piece of text from an FTP server via PowerShell and get it as a string. After performing the required task, I need to upload it to the same server as a different file. The file must not be saved to the local storage at any point.

For a file on a regular HTTP server, the code would be `(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($uri);` for downloading and `(New-Object Net.WebClient).UploadString($uri, $output);"` for sending it to the server for processing via a POST request.

Comment: try googling aound, this is a pretty common question. http://windowsitpro.com/windows/ftp-using-powershell

Comment: @ConnorLSW I checked but didn't find anything regarding manipulation of the file contents as a string.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing FTP implementation that entirely skips local storage, you'll need to configure jobs on the remote server to do this if you need that, or you can simply save it to a temp folder.

Comment: That too is possible, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to replace `DownloadFile` with `DownloadString` and `UploadFile` with `UploadString` in the following answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/936941/5961780

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DownloadString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring) and [`UploadString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring), as all [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) methods, work for `ftp://` URLs too:

> By default, the .NET Framework supports URIs that begin with `http:`, `https:`, `ftp:`, and `file:` scheme identifiers.

---

So unless you need some fancy options, it's as simple as:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$contents = $webclient.DownloadString("ftp://ftp.example.com/file.txt")
```

---

If you need to authenticate to the FTP server, either add credentials to the URL:

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/file.txt
```

Or use [`WebClient.Credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials):

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword") 
$contents = $webclient.DownloadString("ftp://ftp.example.com/file.txt")
```

Comment: How to add authentication to it?

Comment: Both methods give the following error: `Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."
At line:1 char:1
+ IEX $webclient.DownloadString('ftp://host2.bakop.com/im.ps1');`

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have used correct credentials? Do you have an access to FTP server log? Or can you do FTP packet capture?

Comment: The credentials are correct, I can use tools like ssh and scp, but the above code gives an error. Here is the WireShark Capture: http://imgur.com/XPWrZYK

Comment: It's clear "login incorrect" => credentials are incorrect! Nothing we can help you with. Unless you prove that you can login with any FTP client using the same credentials (SSH and SCP are irrelevant here).

Comment: I tried with another client, it worked, though I was asked for the password twice (on all attempts). I'm contacting the hosting provider for additional support. BTW thanks for the code, I will be needing it soon (after this issue is resolved).

Comment: Show us a log file of the client.

Comment: You have removed the Wireshark capture, so I cannot compare it + Stop posting log file as images + We cannot see the second password prompt in the "image" anyway.